# Disable Matlab symbolic rational approximation

Tags: matlab, symbols, symbolic-math

Matlab Symbolic tool has a very annoying feature to me. It automatically convert to rational/decimal values.

**Example 1**

```
z = sym('z', 'real');
f = 3^(1/2)*z;
```

we get expected Matlab return `f = 3^(1/2)*z`

**Example 2**

```
z = sym('z', 'real');
f = 3^(1/3)*z;
```

Then I got crappy result `f = (3247657313705851*z)/2251799813685248`, not desired `f=3^(1/3)*z`

The reason for this can be found [here](https://se.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html#bun735q-flag). By default `sym()` use rational approximation to the numbers.

**My question is, how to disable this feature? For example, how to get return `f=3^(1/3)*z` from the Example 2?**

Comment: Re '[I don't get your definition At={X(t)=Y(t)}. It's a set of what? Do you mean {w∈Ω:X(t)=Y(t)}](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784571/what-is-the-difference-between-a-version-and-a-modification-of-a-stochastic-proc/2762115?noredirect=1#comment7727039_2762115)?' Yes, but why do you ask about my notation, when I'm kinda just using notation of others?

Comment: @BCLC Hmmmm??? What happened?

Comment: Nathan Explosion, you can edit my answer if you want. I currently can't since currently suspended / Re [your comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784571/what-is-the-difference-between-a-version-and-a-modification-of-a-stochastic-proc#comment7731387_2762115)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation you link to tells you how to work around this by forcing numeric values to be computed symbolically. In this case, it's the `1/3` piece that can't be represented with sufficient precision in `double`, so you can do:

```
f = 3 ^ (sym(1)/sym(3)) * z;
```

Comment: (in addition to this answer:) Noticed that you don't necessarily need to convert all your numeric value to `sym`, matlab auto-cast your numeric value to symbolic number if you have at least one symbolic number, so `f = sym(3) ^ (1/3) * z` will produce the same output.

Comment: True enough, but you're at the mercy of MATLAB's execution order - I chose to force `sym(1)/sym(3)` because that's never going to go well in double-precision.

Comment: See the section named "Create Symbolic Numbers"

Comment: This link should take you straight there: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html#bu1rs8g-1